# S3 listObjects API returns wrong data

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, callback, aws-sdk

I have the following folder structure in S3.

> photos/id1/gallery/pic1
>   photos/id2/gallery/pic2
>   photos/id3/menu/pic3

I have written the following snippet to list the pics in each of the id

```
var restids=['id1','id2','id3'];
for(var i=0;i<restids.length;i++)
    {
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var getparams ={Bucket:'photos' , Marker:restids[i]+'/'};
                (function(par){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                          s3.listObjects(par,function(err,data){
                          if(err){
                            console.log('err fetching images from s3 '+err);
                          }
                          else{
                            console.log(_.pluck(data.Contents,'Key'));
                          }
                        });
                    });
                })(getparams);
            });
        })(i);
    }
```

The expected result for the above snippet is

> ['id1/gallery/pic1']
>      ['id2/gallery/pic2']
>   ['id3/menu/pic3']

But the actual result is

> ['id1/gallery/pic1']
>   ['id1/gallery/pic1','id2/gallery/pic2']
>   ['id1/gallery/pic1','id2/gallery/pic2','id3/menu/pic3']

Each of the return value contains the values from the previous calls.
I could not understand this weird behavior.
Is it due to the callbacks or is there a problem with the API itself or is there a problem with my code?
I would really appreciate if anyone could explain me this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong parameters in listObjects. The API call should have been like this
`var getparams ={Bucket:'photos' , Prefix:restids[i]+'/'}`
instead of
`var getparams ={Bucket:'photos' , Marker:restids[i]+'/'}`